# Which apt repository to add for kdeplasma-addons?

Tags: 20.04, kde, add-apt-repository

I'm unable to install kdeplasma-addons.

Seeing the following error:
`E: Unable to locate package kdeplasma-addons`

Unsure as to which repository to add to overcome this.

Comment: Hello. All I did was a google search on your unable and I got this. https://www.devmanuals.net/install/ubuntu/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/install-kdeplasma-addons.html IF that package still exists today that should work even though it is yes years old.

Comment: Try following this guide (I hate this page, but it has viable and working solutions):https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/kdeplasma-addons

Comment: @Logan - That zoomadmin.com site is a spam site that just has an index of all debian packages and makes a cookie cutter page for each package. Complete waste of time.

Comment: @TimothyC.Quinn

I have found some solutions here before. You are partially correct